# not getting the jco color palette in the melted time series

Tags: r, color-palette

I'm trying to plot a time series with 3 variables. to plot it I'm using the melt function and have the jco color palette from `ggsci`. also remove the variable title part from the legend. I'm using the following code to plot it, However, I'm still getting the default colours.

```
    mdf<-melt(df,id.vars="DATE")

g <- ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=DATE, y=value, group = variable,colour=variable))+
  geom_line(linewidth=0.05)+
  scale_fill_jco(name="", #keeping title of legend blank
  breaks=c("V1", "V2","V3"),
  labels=c("First", "Second", "third"))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 years"), labels = date_format("%Y"),expand = c(0, 0)) +
  
  labs(y= "Mean precipitation(mm)", x = "Year")
g
```

the data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(
    0.299709245928855, 0.264898804581009, 0.0514762211257873, 0.172528797343094,
    0.286692151182817, 0.381306320393445, 0.209173997269107, 0.0271853802231936,
    0.0773644637950056, 0.100304007028023
  ),
  V2 = c(
    0.0656779733249077, 0.252630359185351, 0.35086728952018, 0.337186818513385,
    0.495255439470686, 0.913847169790918, 0.358945167549019, 0.849737426926668,
    1.0342232107347, 1.2839730181513
  ),
  V3 = c(
    0.11712306002031, 0.326976704286807, 0.44465221799287, 0.428882415544564,
    0.606684040009608, 1.13251218973981, 0.454452665889777, 1.05901363917576,
    1.29908926601187, 1.63183343004054
  ),
  DATE = as.Date(c(
    "1971-01-01", "1971-01-02", "1971-01-03", "1971-01-04", "1971-01-05",
    "1971-01-06", "1971-01-07", "1971-01-08", "1971-01-09", "1971-01-10"
  ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scale_color_jco` because your are mapping the `color` in your aesthetics for lines. Also you could use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to a longer format like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)
library(scales)
df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = V1:V3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=DATE, y=value, group = name, colour=name))+
  geom_line(linewidth=0.05)+
  scale_color_jco(name="", #keeping title of legend blank
                 breaks=c("V1", "V2","V3"),
                 labels=c("First", "Second", "third"))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 years"), labels = date_format("%Y"),expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y= "Mean precipitation(mm)", x = "Year")
```

[image]

---

Without changing `linewidth`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsci)
library(scales)
df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = V1:V3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=DATE, y=value, group = name, colour=name))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_jco(name="", #keeping title of legend blank
                 breaks=c("V1", "V2","V3"),
                 labels=c("First", "Second", "third"))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 years"), labels = date_format("%Y"),expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(y= "Mean precipitation(mm)", x = "Year")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>